# Out of memory while calling stored procedure

Tags: php, pdo, odbc

I have troubles with retriving data from stored procedure that writes data to database. Connection is estabilished correctly, because other procedures, the ones that only return data without writing (like "call rec.getProducts()"), works well. Whenever I execute following code, I got an error:

```
Out of memory (allocated 262144) (tried to allocate -3 bytes)
```

The procedure declaration looks like that:

```sql
OUT MSG VARCHAR(300),       
OUT STATE CHAR(5),
OUT @IDORDER  dec(10, 0),
IN @NAME char(20),
IN @IDPAYER dec(6, 0),                   
IN @PRODUCT char(10),
```

My php code:

```php
$conn = new PDO(...);

$sql = "{call rec.saveProduct(?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
$rs = $conn->prepare($sql);
$rs->bindParam(1, $msg, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT,300);
$rs->bindParam(2, $state, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT,5);
$rs->bindParam(3, $idOrder, PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT,10);
$rs->bindParam(4, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$rs->bindParam(5, $idPayer, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$rs->bindParam(6, $product, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$rs->execute();
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When I write my stored procedure I prefer to only pass input params:

```
IN @NAME char(20),
IN @IDPAYER dec(6, 0),                   
IN @PRODUCT char(10),
```

Then inside I return the output as a resultset:

```
SELECT @MSG AS [MSG], @STATE AS [STATE], @IDORDER AS [IDORDER]
```

Then in PHP:

```
$sql = "{call rec.saveProduct(?,?,?)}";
$rs = $conn->prepare($sql);
$rs->bindParam(1, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$rs->bindParam(2, $idPayer, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$rs->bindParam(3, $product, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$rs->execute();
$row = $rs->fetch();

$msg = $row['MSG'];
$state = $row['STATE'];
$idOrder = $row['IDORDER'];
```